# hide/show button change when Click

Tags: jquery, html, button, hide, show

Hi, I write code like this :

```
<div id="vip"><a href="javascript:void(0);" " id="vip"> Show </a></div>
<div id="vip2"></div>
```

JS:

```
var toggle = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#vip" ).click(function() {
if (toggle) {
  $("#vip2").toggle("slow");
} else {
  toggle = true;


      $.ajax({
          url: "showthread.php?10-Podania-V-I-P",
          type: "GET",            
          success: function(data) {
            data=$(data).find('#post_message_11');
            $('#vip2').html(data);
               $( "#vip2" ).animate({
               width:"100%",
               },600 );
            }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How can I do something like this: First time when page load the button or selector `<a>` show "Show content" when I click on this "show content" the button or selector change to "Hide content".

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
            $(this).text('Hide Content') 
            data=$(data).find('#post_message_11');
            $('#vip2').html(data);
               $( "#vip2" ).animate({
               width:"100%",
               },600 );
            }
```

just add $(this).text('Hide Content') in your callback.